# Fedora location of /usr/share/v86d/initramfs

Tags: fedora, initramfs

I compiled and installed v86d, yet I can only locate one binary file in /sbin. There is supposed to be the initramfs file in /usr/share/v86d, but this directory does not exist. I don't think that the location of this file should vary between distros, but I am using fedora 15 and it isn't there.

Notes: Compiled with klibc against a custom kernel tree

I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you compiled it, and didn't specify a custom `--prefix` to `configure` script, then your binaries have probably ended up below /usr/local.

If you know names of the files which you want to track down, you can use `find` or `locate` (if `updatedb` run since the installation) to learn where they are.